# Someone asking for my phrase?

Tags: wallets

If someone asks me for my ethereum phrase, are they referring to my address or public key or are they trying to gain access to my acccount?

Comment: Address is simply called address. 
Phrase means the main password to your account never share it.

Comment: Having your phrase, the holder can access all your addresses and its associated funds. DONT SHARE IT. STORE IT SAFE.